# cd into a specific directory inside a Git repo

Tags: git, shell, fish

I have multiple project trees that are based on the same remote repo. I want to cd into a specific directory in any of them but based on where is PWD at this moment.

Example:

If I have 3 clones

```
clone1
clone2
clone3
```

And when in clone2/test/
I want to be able to do CDGOTO and will automatically go to some directory like

```
clone2/test/test1/test2/foo
```

So the shell command would evaluate the current git repo I am in then cd into that repo looking for the interesting directory.

If I was in clone1 then CDGOTO will go to:

```
clone1/test/test1/test2/foo
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
alias CDGOTO='cd $(git rev-parse --show-toplevel)/test/test1/test2/foo'
```

Comment: FYI, That isn't legal fish syntax. Use parens instead of backticks for command substitution.

Comment: Tnx, fixed. Is that better now?